# Youtube browser upload with flash (Security error #2049)

Tags: flash, youtube, crossdomain.xml

I'am trying to upload video to Youtube with flash from browser. Usual HTML form created with [official API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python#UploadingVideos) works fine, but I need progress bar.

I'm trying to use SWFUpload, Uploadify and Yahoo UI, but all uploaders throws Security Error #2049. I guess this means crossdomain.xml file rejects my request, right?

Youtube's crossdomain.xml located in https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/crossdomain.xml. I can see this request in browser when trying to upload. I've tested both localhost and App Engine -- same error is occured.

Could you give me a tips? Tnanks.

Answer (score 2):

OK, solution was replacing HTTPS with HTTP in upoad url.
I dont know yet, why flash can't send HTTPS request (m.b, proxy?).